# Connecting to TCP server running in a machine connected to private home LAN

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I like to connect to a TCP server that run in a machine that is connected to the LAN in my home network. This LAN can be connected to internet via either following methods. 
1. Through a router which has a wireless or wired WAN connection
2. Through a router which uses a mobile broadband connection, for example a router that accept a USB modem to connect to internet.

I know in the first case, we can use port forwarding. 
In the second case, I believe telcos use PPP protocol and port forwarding does not work.
In addition, even in the first case, if ISP does not give a static IP, then we need to use DNS mapping service to map a fixed URL to the allocated dynamic IP and we need to configure router to go and register the dynamic ip at the start up.

My question is, are there any other better methods that can be used in this situation? I am wondering how chat applications connect to each other? I hope they maintain a TCP connection between two devices, without a central relay server?

Comment: what chat applications are you talkig about? Anyway even with PPP you should get a public ip on the router that usually does masquerading nat for your server, and on the router you could do port forwarding, isn't this the case?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. It looks like with ppp. Its the ISP who get the public IP which forwards all traffic to our router which in not known to internet. My application is reading media files in home network from internet.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you are connected to your ISP.  Your internet connection has an ISP-assigned IP address. All traffic from the outside world that needs to reach your home network must be sent to that IP address, which is then delivered by the ISP to your internet modem, which is then delivered to whatever device is connected to the modem (whether that be a PC or a router), and so on. If you run a server on your network, your router needs to have port forwarding configured, and outside client would connect to your ISP-assigned IP address. Connecting to the ISP via PPP does not change that.